# SHow image from Push notification in ios sdk

Tags: ios, uiimageview, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am new to ios and PNS, i am working on push notification in which i am getting URL in notification based on this i need to show image into image view. i got PNS succesfully also got URL using payload but its not showing in image view in another class
Below is code i am using

```
  - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) // If app is running and you got notification then show it 
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Did receive a Remote Notification" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You Have a Notification :\n%@",userInfo[@"aps"][@"alert"]]delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alertView show];
}
NSLog(@"Payload: %@", userInfo);
imageURL =  userInfo[@"aps"][@"alert"];
MainViewController *mv =  [[MainViewController alloc] init];
[mv.ansinage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cartoon.png"]]; // Right now i am setting image in resource but still not setting in mainviewcontrller when i am open app

}
```

Comment: You could **refer the image to the MainViewController**.  It is not possible by the way you are doing ...

Comment: can you plase explain in more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void) sshowansimage:(NSString *) strImageURL{

NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:strImageURL];
NSLog(@"coming URL is %@", strImageURL);
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:strImageURL];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showImage:) withObject:imageData waitUntilDone:YES];
});
```

}

```
-(void)showImage:(NSData*)imageAsData
{
NSLog(@"IN image view mthhod data is %d",imageAsData.length);
ansinage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageAsData];

}
```